# Compare multiple columns from a single file an count the occurrence of a value in these columns

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with 21 columns;

```
Name    Grade1    Grade2   Grade3   Grade4   Grade5  .... Grade20
Zoe       60        70      NA       NA        NA            67
```

Now, I want to keep only the names that have more than 5 Grades that are  NA. **Some names contains NA.**

I know that awk can do the job. But I'm not sure how to compare all of the columns without having to compare them individually.

I tried:

```
    more input_file.txt | awk 'total = count20[$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,
    $11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21]++, if (($2 == "NA" || $3 == "NA" || 
    $4 == "NA" || $5 == "NA" || $6 == "NA" || $7 == "NA" || $8 == "NA" || $9 == "NA" 
    || $10 == "NA" || $11 == "NA" || $12 == "NA" || $13 == "NA" || $14 == "NA" || 
    $15 == "NA" || $16 == "NA" || $17 == "NA" || $18 == "NA" || $19 == "NA" || 
    $20 == "NA" || $21 == "NA") && total > 4) { print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"
    $6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"$12"\t"$13"\t"$14"\t"$15"\t"$16"\t"$17"\t"
    $18"\t"$19"\t"$20"\t"$21 }' > test.txt
```

It doesn't work and I'm not sure why or how to do it more efficiently.

Edit: to be more precise, the wanted output is a file containing name and all columns for students having more than 5 columns containing NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly basic way to do it using awk:

```
awk '{ count = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == "NA") ++count } count > 5' file
```

This loops through each field and checks whether it is equal to "NA". If so, it adds to the total count for that record. Records are printed when the count is greater than 5.

Comment: This is the only one where student "NAthalie Miller" with 5 NAs isn't a false positive ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. it WAS the only one... :-).

Comment: I guess that now, the only thing going for it is that it's the least scary-looking :)

Comment: @TomFenech 
 
I added $1="" to skip the first column (so that the condition doesn't affect the name) but now it doesn't output the names. Is there something I should add to output all columns?

Comment: I'm only looping from the second field so the first field shouldn't affect the count. Also, the fields are being tested for an exact match with "NA".

Comment: @TomFenech Ohh, ok! Sorry! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'NA' 'NF>5'
```

assuming your names column doesn't include NA as a substring.  Use NA as the field delimiter and count the fields, if there are more than 5 fields means there are at least 5 NAs, default action is printing the line so no need to specify.  This will give you the records with 5 or more NA, change the threshold to 6 if you want strictly more than 5.

Comment: I'm not sure that "`awk` to the rescue" is an appropriately detailed answer, especially when the OP has already attempted to use awk!

Answer (score 1):

This command prints all lines containing `NA` at least six times:

```
grep -E '(NA.*){6}' infile
```

It can be tripped up if the name of the student contains `NA` as well. To fix that, you can use

```
grep -E '^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+(NA.*){6,}' infile
```

which counts the `NA` only *after* the first column.

Comment: Is there as way, with your 2nd method, to have the NA for max 6 occurences (and not a least 6)?

Comment: It is not working. It just outputs the whole file. In this case, I only want to output the rows that contain max 6 NA.

Comment: @snowy_squirrel Ah, right. To say "6 or less", you can use the same pattern as for "7 or more", but invert the matches with `-v`: `grep -vE '^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+(NA.*){7,}' infile`

Answer (score 0):

It's tagged `perl` so a perl answer:

```
perl -ne 'print if (grep /^NA$/, split ) > 5'
```

Which:

- iterates line by line
- does a whitespace split
- greps fields that are *just* `NA`
- prints if the count of those are `> 5`

Comment: I guess you could just use `-a` instead of calling `split`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for word boundaries:

```
awk -F'\\<NA\\>' 'NF>6'
```

with any awk if your fields are tab-separated as they seem to be:

```
awk -F'\tNA(\t|$)' 'NF>6'
```

with any POSIX awk for any type of space between fields:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]NA([[:space:]]|$)' 'NF>6'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, just count the number of fields that are equal to `NA`

```
perl -ne 'print if 5 <= grep { $_ eq "NA" } split' test.txt
```

or, as Tom Fenech points out in his comment

```
perl -ane 'print if 5 <= grep { $_ eq "NA" } @F' test.txt
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer calling `split` over using `-a` and `@F`?

Comment: @TomFenech: Only that it saves very little in this case, and it's less clear for those who aren't fully au fait with the contents of [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). I've added a version using *autosplit* to my answer